# Facebook Pixel: What does Content View event "Value" in Facebook Analytics mean?

Tags: facebook, pixel, facebook-pixel, facebook-analytics, contentview

Sorry if this may have been asked before. I can't seem to find the answer after all the searching. Just wanted to understand what the "Value" column means as regards the Content View standard event. Here's a screenshot:[As viewed in Facebook Analytics dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW6JP.png)

Answer (score 0):

This number gives the value of a user performing this event to the business. So let's say you would like to attract leads via your website. When someone lands on the home page, this has a value of 5. They are interested in something, but you need to give them direction. When this person clicks on services, the value increases to 20. This might be a potential lead. Now, he/she would like to get in touch with sales and fills in the get in touch form. The value increases to 100 because this action is good for business.

So basically, you look at your business and website and assign values to the actions someone performs on your website. These insights will show you how your website is an extension for your business or not.